# Azure Devops: value cannot be null, parameter token

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am running an Azure Powershell task in Azure DevOps.
Inside the script I use the following command

```
Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $adusernameNewPermission
```

But my Release pipeline fails with following error code

```
 ##[error]Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: token
```

First I thought that the command didn't have the right context or enough permission so I've added the defaultprofile.

```
Get-AzureRmADUser -DefaultProfile (Get-AzureRmContext) -UserPrincipalName $adusernameNewPermission
```

The GetAzureRmContext did go to the right context if I print the output of that command.

The command itself didn't had any problem when running locally (with my own user account) So the only reason I think its heading is that the service connection doesn't have the right to perform that action. But my user account has the least permissions on the tenant whilst the service connnection in azure devops has much more permissions.

It's driving me crazy where the problem lays with this one. Which token does it mean ? No reasonable error message :( 
Does someone encounter the same problem or knows what I am missing ?

PS: the $adusernameNewPermission variable works like I said the exact same code runs perfectly on my local machine with the only difference being the user that is logged in.

Comment: What does `$adusernameNewPermission` contain?

Comment: @Bevan an username from my aad

Comment: Need a bit more info. What is the output of `write-host $adusernameNewPermission`? How is the value assigned? Via another command or static entry? Is it as an object or a string? If via another command use ` | select -expandproperty Name` to make sure the `var` is a string.

Comment: this is achahbar@domainStackoverflow.com 
a user that I want to retrieve the object ID from. 
By doing this with the command Get-AzureAD

Comment: Did you enable 'allow scripts to access Oauth'?

Comment: Have you tested functionality by having a simple string like the examples in my answer below?

Comment: @Bevan yes I did. I tried the solution you provided below with the simple string but still nothing.
VisualBean yes i did

Comment: @achahbar did you remember to 'Allow scripts to acces OAuth'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the service connection in Azure DevOps that was created with a managed identity. I created a new service connection with a service principal and this doesn't gave me any errors about the value token. Hope any person who looks for this issue in the future got an answer by this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Get-azureaduser instead? This is a command that requires the function to be authenticated against Azure AD.

```
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:client_secret -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($env:clientid , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $env:tenantid -ServicePrincipal
```

Comment: I tried using your solution but the azure devops user doesn't have enough permissions to download the module AzureAD for this command.
However I can't figure out why my command Get-AzureRmADUSer fails because the powershell task in azure DevOps uses Azure Powershell and uses a service principal that has the rights to connect to the ad ?

Comment: That might be possible yes. You can try going to your application registration --> API Permissions --> Assign the Azure AD application permissions for being able to read users. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
This was already the case , the app registration did have this permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Script Type of "Script File Path," check that you're not trying to pass in any arguments (such as -token).

Comment: Hi @Wahid
No I tried both ways, with Script File Path providing the right arguments for the script (no token).
And for testing purposes I also tested the Inline Script.
But both gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try 2 things to get back to basics. This will let you know if it is actually the AzDO Service Principal or not and the type of object to use in the pipeline.

1. Test the functionality of the command in its simplest form and run it with the account as a string:

```
Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName "achahbar@stankoverflow.com"

#OR

$UPN = "achahbar@stankoverflow.com"
Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN
```

Assuming this works and depending on what your variable contains you simply need to pass the the UPN/Email object into the command:

```
Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $adusernameNewPermission.UPN
```

2. If this doesn't work pdate your task to Version 4 (Preview) and update your commands to `Get-AzADUser` and test step `1.` again